# Run Simulink from Matlab function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am running Simulink using FastRestart, as I need to start and stop the simulation multiple times changing parameters. When I run Simulink from the main script, there are no problems. However, as soon as I make the script a function so that I can run it for different input data, I get an error that is clearly related to Simulink not seeing the Matlab workspace within the function.

To be more precise, say `sfile` is my Simulink file, then I run the following lines AFTER having initialized all variables I need in structures in Matlab:

```
load_system(sfile);
set_param(sfile,'FastRestart','on');
set_param(sfile,'SaveFinalState','on');
set_param(sfile,'SaveCompleteFinalSimState','on');
set_param(sfile,'SimulationCommand','update');
```

At the last line, I get the error that Simulink does not recognize `mdl.tStep` (which is the time step), as `mdl` is not a recognized structure. In fact, it is and if I run Simulink from the main script everything is fine.

Now, in the past, I would have used

```
options = simset('SrcWorkspace','current');
```

However, an expert I know has advised me against `simset` (as it may get deprecated in the future) and encouraged me to use `set_param` instead. I have 
looked up the options for set_param on-line, but I could not find the setting for the Matlab workspace.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this work: `options = sim(model, 'SrcWorkspace', 'current')` ?

Comment: Not really because before running `sim(sfile,...,options);` I am actually calling `set_param(sfile,'SimulationCommand','update');`

Comment: I know, it's not a very 'clean' solution, but you could try to use `assignin('base','mdl',mdl)` to get your variables into matlabs base workspace which simulink can read.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I had done for all variables. Is there a way to specify the workspace through `assignin`, i.e. a way to specify `base`?

Comment: @EnricoAnderlini sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you want to specify? using `assignin` you can specify the workspace you want to assign the variables to. Assigning them to the base workspace should actually solve your problem

Comment: Yes, after reading the help files for `assignin` I realise my question was wrong. Actually, the solution you suggest with `assignin` is what I tried and it works so if you post an answer, I will accept it. The `update` command still works in the simulation (when I start and stop it), so I do not have to repeat the commands of `assignin` multiple times after the first call, which is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your problem might be to use the `assignin`-function to all the variable whose value you want to pass to simulink in your matlab base workspace. To do so just use

```
assignin('base','mdl',mdl)
```

Having the variable in your base workspace should allow simulink to see it.

Answer (score 4):

In many instances it is better to use the `Model Workspace` rather than the `Base Workspace`:

```
hws = get_param(model, 'modelworkspace');
hws.assignin('mdl',mdl);
```

At least be aware that this option exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!